# How to get the count of rows in a sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying this code

```
row = 2
With Summary
    .Range("$A$1:$A$100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    For row To .Rows.Count
        .Cells(row, 2) = 1
        row = row + 1
    Next row
End With
```

but I get a syntax error in the for loop statement

How should this look like?

Comment: `For` statements are of the form `For variable = start To end [ Step stepvalue ]` so you probably want `For row = 2 To .Rows.Count`

Comment: But see the answer by Gary's Student, which will stop you from filling up every second row, for a million+ rows, with the value 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a `Loop`:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long, summary As Worksheet
    Set summary = ActiveSheet

    With summary
        .Range("$A$1:$A$100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B2:B" & N).Value = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

***Note:*** The code assumes there is nothing else in column **A**.